\FPsv and \FPval esami package commands behave differently when printing numbers in Italian
The esami package provides the commands \FPsv and \FPval for different purposes, however, when these commands print a decimal number in Italian language, the first command uses the comma as a decimal separator whereas the second one uses the point.
For example:
\FPsv[3]{sin(\FPpi/4)} prints 0,707

while
\FPval{\seno}[3]{sin(\FPpi/4)} \seno prints 0.707

It is also worth noting that
\FPsv[3]{\seno}

also prints 0,707
The question is the following: Is there a way to make the macro \seno (as defined earlier) print 0,707 just like \FPsv[2]{sin(\FPpi/4)} ?

Please always post full but minimal examples others can copy and test as is without adding anything.

As far as I can see, \FPsv is for printing values, whereas \FPval is for storing the obtained value, usually to be passed on for further computations. Thus the latter must use a form compatible with fp macros, that want a decimal point.
If you want to print the result stored by \FPval according to the locale, use \num from siunitx.
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{esami}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\date{3012/01/19} % to keep esami quiet

\begin{document}

\FPsv[3]{sin(\FPpi/4)} prints 0,707

%%% Do computations with \FPval between paragraphs
\FPval{\seno}[3]{sin(\FPpi/4)}

Also \num{\seno} prints 0,707

\end{document}

Don't use \FPval inside paragraphs, for better clarity of your printout. If you don't want to follow the advice, don't leave spaces yourself:
Also \FPval{\seno}[3]{sin(\FPpi/4)}\num{\seno} prints 0,707

would be correct, with no space intervening before \num.


Thanks a lot egreg. Just the solution I was looking for!
